# LocationInterceptionAspect: args.Location is returning null

Tags: postsharp

I'm trying to get info in my aspect about the property it's intercepting, but args.Location is null and I have no idea why.

It's multicast from the class to the properties, but I don't think that should matter.  Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: How do you know that args.Location is null? Because you see the property is null in the debugger, or because you get the property value in code and see it is null? If you don't get the property value in code, PostSharp will not generate the code to provide the property value.

Comment: It would probably help to see some example code here - specifically the aspect override method.

Comment: @GaelFraiteur Sorry for not getting back to you.  I took a different apporach and totally forgot about this question until SO just pointed out to me that someone edited it.  All I can tell you is that I was definitely assigning it to a variable, and it was a line of code that was trying to work with that variable that was throwing an exception since it was null.  I'll try to reproduce the problem this week, and I'll post it up here if I'm able to.